# Append items in front to every list inside list of lists, not to the back

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have the following list of lists.

```
list_list = 
[
 [1640, 0.1731, 0.173757, 0.1711825, 0.1726265, 4723572.914018], 
 [1640, 0.1726265, 0.1735915, 0.1715855, 0.1734615, 2590512.353352], 
 [1640, 0.1734615, 0.1750445, 0.1731025, 0.1739595, 1803995.1104755], 
]
```

I would like to append `item_name` to the front of the list such that it looks like this;

```
    item_name = "item"
    new_list_list = 
    [
     ["item", "item", 1640, 0.1731, 0.173757, 0.1711825, 0.1726265, 4723572.914018], 
     ["item", "item", 1640, 0.1726265, 0.1735915, 0.1715855, 0.1734615, 2590512.353352], 
     ["item", "item", 1640, 0.1734615, 0.1750445, 0.1731025, 0.1739595, 1803995.1104755], 
    ]
```

Here is the python code I wrote to do this;

```
item_name = "item"
new_list_list = [item + [item_name] + [item_name] for item in list_of_list]
```

The code appends the items to the back of the list. What I want is append to the front of the list.

I am using python 3.9.

Comment: If you want it at the _start_, why `item + [item_name] + [item_name]`? (While we're here, why not `+ [item_name, item_name]`?)

Comment: `new_list_list  = [[item_name,]*2 + x for x in list_list]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
new_list_list = [[item_name] + [item_name] + item for item in list_of_list]
```

Comment: Heh, very good!

Comment: Thanks. Verified to be correct. Why didn't I think of that? Such a simple change.

Answer (score 1):

This might do the trick:

```py
new_list_list = [[item_name] + [item_name] + item for item in list_of_list]
```